# Fast question about minimum spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

If any edge from a spanning tree T0 is contained in some minimum spanning tree T*, does this imply that T0 is also a minimum spanning tree ?

Right now, I'm trying to draw on paper some graphs to prove that it doesn't. Please correct me if it does, or help me find an example if it doesn't.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this is better asked on mathoverflow.com ?

Comment: Graph theory is also studied at Computer Science.. and supposing a lot of users from SO are either CS students or have an equivalent diploma, I could get help also from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangle with edge weights 2,2,1.

EDIT:

There are three different spanning trees with costs 3 (1+2),3 (2+1) and 4 (2+2) in this graph. all the edges from the spanning tree with cost 4 are contained in one of the minimum spanning trees with cost 3, and it is NOT minimal.